# How to serve locally-checked out SVN repository?

Tags: svn

Let's say that there is an SVN repository, might be [bval](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/bval/). I've checkout this repository with:

```
svn checkout https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/bval/
```

Is there any possibility to make this checked-out repository behave like a remote repository so I can check it out locally once again? `svnserve` does not help.

Comment: You if you want a local repository or project's copy with revision history, use `svnrdump` or `svnsync`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked out sources makes Working Copy. Working Copy is a not full repository with history, etc.

So short answer is: no.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new local repository on your machine and sync the project  https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/bval/ with all its revision history. You could use [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnrdump) or [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync) tools for that. However, your synced copy should be read-only.

BTW, `bval` is not a repository. It is just one of projects in single monolithic Apache Software Foundation that hosts about 200 projects and contains more than 1700000 revisions at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, very useful tip.

Comment: @Opal and it helps you to obtain only the revisions that relate to `bval` project only. You don't need to sync all the 1.7kk revisions from the remote ASF repo.

Comment: I thought so, but have no idea how can I do it. Can you please suggest something?